# How to get output parameter from Python Sybase module

Tags: python

I am stuck with this problem for a while and need your comments.

I have to deal with vendor's procedure call with 2 output parameters (int and varchar). I pick the Python's Sybase module, everything is ok until I found that I can't find the document that describe how to call stored procedure with output parameter.

The main document that always found on Google is http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/news.html. They introduce the function call very shortly:

> Output parameters from stored procedures are supported via the OUTPUT() function. The parameter to OUTPUT() determines the type and size of the buffer which will be allocated to receive the output value.

```
c.callproc('test_proc', {'@type': 'business',
                         '@tot_sales': 5,
                         '@num_books': Sybase.OUTPUT(1)})
```

If the output type is integer, the Sybase.OUTPUT(1) is work correctly but I do not known
how to deal with Varchar (and other type).

For incorrect parameter type, I always get the error:

> DatabaseError: Msg 257, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_caller_id_manage
>   Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'INT' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an instance of CS_DATAFMT() to OUTPUT instead of 1 (they use that everywhere else parameters are passed to the DBMS in Sybase.py).
Try to set the fields datatype and maxlength (and maybe status) of it.